# ^M character suddenly appearing upon opening file

Tags: character-encoding, utf-8

I'm using Emacs on Windows. Everything was fine just a few minutes ago, but for some odd reason, when I open a certain file, I get `^M` characters after every line. As far as I know/remember, I didn't do anything to the file except refile a a couple org-mode items (and they didn't contain any strange characters like smart quotes or anything either)... and yet when I closed then reopened the file a few seconds later, these characters appeared. It only happens for that file; other buffers seem to be okay.

Based on my research, `^M` seems to be the end of line character for Windows.

Following [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EndOfLineTips), executing `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system utf-8-dos` seems to fix the problem until I open the file again, at which point the `^M`s return.

The only encoding-related thing I have in my init.el file is

```
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
```

which hasn't changed since I set them a couple months ago.

Does anyone have any idea what happened?

**Update**: One thing I noticed (after disabling my modeline theme) is that the file in question seems to always want to revert to `(Unix)` Unix-style LF line endings, when all my other (working) files are set to `\` DOS-style CRLF line endings. I have some characters like é and あ in my file, but they hadn't caused problems before...

Here's a comparison of the modeline indicators:

- (Working) File with no `^M`, no foreign characters: `-\` undecided-dos, DOS-style CRLF
- (Not working) File with `^M`, with foreign characters: `=(Unix)` no-conversion, Unix-style LF
- (Working) File with no `^M`, with foreign characters: `U\` utf-8-dos, CRLF

The "not working" file always seems to want to open with (Unix) and no-conversion...

**Update 2**: I seem to have temporarily been able to solve this by forcing the buffer to read the file as utf-8-dos by including `# -*- coding: utf-8-dos -*-` at the top.

I will leave this question open, however, as I still would like to know what caused this, and why emacs suddenly decided it wanted to encode the file as `no-conversion` even though it had been handling foreign characters just fine earlier in the day...

Comment: does the file start with `# -*- coding: utf-8-unix -*-`, or, near the bottom? Or, describe-variable on `require-final-newline` and `mode-require-final-newline`. Emacs might added a newline while it still think the file is utf-8-unix.

Comment: No, that line doesn't appear anywhere in the file. `require-final-newline` and `mode-require-final-newline` are both set to `t` for all the files (working and not working).

Comment: Can you reproduce this if you open the file in `emacs -q`? in `emacs -Q`? If not then you need to post your init file. Can you share a file without any private data that reproduces the problem? Do you have the same issue if with a copy of that file? with a copy with a different name and extension?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure *every* line ends with a ^M? If just a single one doesn't then you will get the symptoms you describe.

You can search for such lines with isearch-forward-regexp, e.g.

```
escape ctrl-s [ ^ ctrl-q ctrl-m ] $
```

The [^^m] matches any character that is not ctrl-m, and the dollar matches the end of line.

When you find a line which is missing a ctrl-m, you can add one with

```
ctrl-e ctrl-q ctrl-m
```

Once you have changed all the lines you can save the file and reload it, and hopefully the issue will have gone away.

Comment: Fair enough - searching for anything that isn't `^M` points me to the very last line of the file.

Comment: So a file where every line ends with ^m^j then it is taken to use ^m^j as the the end of line indicator (unless you override it). If only most do, then ^j is the end of line and the ^m is just another character like e or t.

Comment: If that's the case, then it's a matter of why emacs is inserting a ^j at the end of the file (could this have to do with the `require-final-newline` setting?), right? If I delete the `^M`s at the end of the file, save, and reopen, however, the problem still remains.

Comment: If the file is opened with the correct encoding then the `require-final-newline` setting should make it add ^m^j. My suggestion is to add ^m to files where they are missing, not to delete existing ^m characters.